# Trouble assigning values to an array of objects in Java, using a for loop and object methods

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, object, methods

In my **Time** class i have:

```
public Time(String start_time) 
    {
    time = start_time;
    hrs = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0, 2));
    mins = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(3, 5));
    secs = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(6, 8));
    }
```

and

```
public void addHour()
  {
    hrs = hrs + 1;

    }
    if (hrs > 23) {
      hrs = hrs - 24;
    }

    prntsecs = String.valueOf(secs);
    prntmins = String.valueOf(mins);
    prnthrs = String.valueOf(hrs);

    if (secs < 10) {
      prntsecs = "0" + String.valueOf(secs);
    }
    if (mins < 10) {
      prntmins = "0" + String.valueOf(mins);
    }
    if (hrs < 10) {
      prnthrs = "0" + String.valueOf(hrs);
    }

    time = prnthrs + ":" + prntmins + ":" + prntsecs;
  }
```

In my **Main** class i have:

```
Time tstamps[] = new Time[5];
Time a = new Time("09:00:00");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  tstamps[i] = a;
  a.addHour();
}

tstamps[0].printTime();
tstamps[1].printTime();
tstamps[2].printTime();
tstamps[3].printTime();
tstamps[4].printTime();
```

I want it to print:

09:00:00
10:00:00
11:00:00
12:00:00
13:00:00

But it prints:

14:00:00
14:00:00
14:00:00
14:00:00
14:00:00

I've tried messing around with the code in my Main class, but I'm very much a beginner, please help me understand my mistake and how to fix it...

**Edit:**

Sorry, I still don't quite understand how to do this...

I tried to follow your advice and did this:

```
Time tstamps[] = new Time[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      Time a = new Time("09:00:00");
      for (int j = 1; j < i; j++){
        a.addHour();
      }
      tstamps[i] = a;
    }
```

But now it just prints 09:00:00 five times, instead of 14:00:00.

My field definitions for the Time class:

```
public String time;
public String prntsecs;
public String prntmins;
public String prnthrs;
public int hrs;
public int mins;
public int secs;
```

I don't have any for the **Main** class.

*Also, please excuse me if I break any community norms, or something of the sort, this is my second time ever posting on StackOverflow.*

Comment: You keep adding the same object in evert box, you need a new one for each

Comment: You are using the same Object each time `tstamps[i] = a;` - create a new Object for each iteration of your loop.

Comment: I assume this is for a class assignment - I will point out that `addHour` should never need to adjust any value(s) beside hours - how would seconds or minutes change ***in*** `addHour`?). Finally, Java has `LocalTime` in the `java.time` package (which is what you should be using in real projects). As well as **multiple** other classes for representing time (like too many classes for representing time).

Comment: @ScaryWombat Hey, thank you for your help, but unfortunately still don't quite understand how to do this. I completely failed at writing a legible comment with the code, so I included it in an edit at the bottom of my post.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes, it is, thank you so much for your comment, i fixed the 'addHour' and other methods with the same problem. I'll stick with the time system I created for this one, but I'll be sure to check if these things aren't already out there next time.

Comment: Please show the field defintions

Comment: *so I included it in an edit at the bottom of my post.* - this is where it **should** be.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Added the field definitions. Thank you again for all your help.

Comment: Your code does not seem to compile `public void addHour()
  {
    hrs = hrs + 1;

    }`  - is this closing bracket correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon your posted code - but removing the compile error from `addHour`

and modifying to

```
    Time tstamps[] = new Time[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      Time a = new Time("09:00:00");
      for (int j = 1; j < i + 1; j++){   // changed
        a.addHour();
      }
      tstamps[i] = a;
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        System.out.println(tstamps[x].time);
    }
```

I get the output

```
09:00:00
10:00:00
11:00:00
12:00:00
13:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly!! It looks like I accidentally created the compile error while writing the question and trying to fix my code, I undid most of my messing around, used your changes, and now it's all working smoothly :) I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, using your original code.

```
Time tstamps[] = new Time[5];
Time a = new Time("09:00:00");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  tstamps[i] = a;
  a.addHour();
  a = new Time(a.time);
}
```

Suggestions for improvement(s): Make `Time.addHour()` return a new `Time` that is one hour in the future. That would allow you to simplify the above further. Like,

```
Time tstamps[] = new Time[5];
Time a = new Time("09:00:00");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  tstamps[i] = a;
  a = a.addHour();
}
```

or

```
Time tstamps[] = new Time[5];
tstamps[0] = new Time("09:00:00");
for (int i = 1; i < tstamps.length; i++) {
  tstamps[i] = tstamps[i-1].addHour();
}
```